# Resize div with aspect ratio to fit content css image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hello I have a div and as background I have an image with width 1920px and height 1200px.
divs have 100% width and `window.innerHeight` on document ready;

The background css images have the follwoing rule: `background-size: 100% auto !important;`
so that they are responsive

What I would like to do is based on window.resize calculate the new height for the div element and set it so that it matches the background-images css height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
newHeight = (1200 * divWidth) / 1920
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you don't need js

```
background: url(../img/image.png) no-repeat center top fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```